# Keyboard shortcut to go to end of line in Windows

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Stupid question.  I hate using the "End" key to go to the end of the line because its not within easy reach on my keyboard.  Are there any other better shortcuts to go to the end of the line or is there any where I can tell Windows to use another hotkey to accomplish this?  Thanks.

Comment: How is this not programming related?  I need to go to the end of the line while I'm coding.

Comment: You can use a thing called "SharpKeys" to remap any key to any other key.

Comment: Sometimes I need to change which album I'm listening to while I'm coding. This does not, alas, make said activity programming related.

Comment: vi or emacs key bindings?

Comment: I find it odd that this was marked off topic. Surely using hotkeys on a keyboard fits into the category of "Questions about general computing hardware and software... [that] directly involve tools used primarily for programming." Is the keyboard primarily used for programming? Perhaps not, but you'll find programming is a hard task without a keyboard, making it a crucial addition